# Versioned Settings Teamcity

Tags: git, teamcity-9.0

Recently enabled Versioned Settings in Teamcity (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control) with Git.

The first synchronisation failed since the user I setup did not have write privileges. This caused the builds to have a red error message against their status.

I amended the vcs root to enable write privileges and it commits successfully now however the red errors lines still remain! Any idea how to refresh the status since the errors are now weeks old but the build status is successful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the user not having all privileges such as being able to list remotes